# Node.js not searching modules in node_modules folder

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-14.04

I have installed packages using `npm install -g http-server`.
However, when i try to run this using `node http-server`. it throws error as below:

```
module.js:338
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module '/home/khagesh/http-server'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

I have tried setting `NODE_PATH` to `/home/khagesh/npm/lib/node_modules`.
As far as i can think is that node is not searching modules in `node_modules` and directly searching in user directory. 
I am running it on Ubuntu 14.04.
Any help to fix this issue is appreciated.

Comment: what do you see if you do an npm list versus an npm -g list?

Comment: @GrumbleSnatch both gives same output. Have http-server installed

Comment: Did you try only http-server [path] [options]
where [path] defaults to ./public if the folder exists, and ./ otherwise or node bin/http-server?

Comment: @dbucki it does not work even if i pass other options. It is not working for any modules that i install, locally or globally. However, it does work if i give full path to node_modules directory `node /home/khagesh/npm/lib/node_modules/http-server/bin/http-server`. this works fine.